# Ho to get UDT members by SQL?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get user defined type members by SQL but I can't figure out how to do it.

For the moment I'm trying the following query but it's giving only the name of the types. Not the details of the members...

```
    select * from USER_OBJECTS  where object_type = 'TYPE'
```

Let's say I have an object as follows. I need to return the members **FirstName varchar2(20)** and **LastName varchar2(25)**.

I'm talking about the type members not instance values. Like reflection in .Net

```
    create or replace TYPE person AS OBJECT (  
      firstname     VARCHAR2(20),
      lastname      VARCHAR2(25))
```

Does anyone know how to do that plaese ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select attr_name, attr_type_name, length 
  from user_type_attrs 
  where type_name = 'PERSON';
```

Result:

```
ATTR_NAME                      ATTR_TYPE_NAME                     LENGTH
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
FIRSTNAME                      VARCHAR2                               20
LASTNAME                       VARCHAR2                               25
```